# Power BI Filter Context - adding a measure to matrix then ignores all relationships

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have a very simple data model with one relationship, and it works as expected (on the left). However, when I add a measure that's always valid (in this case, something that displays today's date), the visuals I have ignore the relationships in my model and display all combinations of values, even if they're not valid or matching in the data model.

What's going on here? I would expect that the measure, which has no filter context of its own, would be run for each row and just display today's date. What seems to be happening, though, is that it's being evaluated for every single combination of values, even when the relationship should already be excluding those.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A measure isn't really associated with a table so the relationships and filters only apply to them insofar as the measure involves tables and columns. This is useful in cases where you want to write a measure that involves unrelated tables since otherwise those wouldn't be possible.

Since your date measure doesn't involve any tables, it's not constrained by their relationship. You can force it to be though. For example,

```
Today Date = IF ( NOT ( ISEMPTY ( Ones ) ), TODAY () )
```

or more implicitly with something like this

```
Today Date = MAXX ( Ones, TODAY () )
```

Comment: That makes sense and your suggested solution removes the "incorrect" rows perfectly. I'm still a bit confused on the reasoning - even if the measure isn't constrained because it doesn't have a context, I would expect the relationship to constrain the combinations of table values that can be displayed together - just because my measure is valid doesn't mean that those two values from different tables belong together. I was expecting it to display every valid combination in my dataset and the measure on every row, but this explains why my issue is incredibly slow on my larger dataset :)

Comment: It behaves like you expect if `Tens` and `Ones` both come from the `Ones` table but treats the tables independently when they're from different tables.

Comment: It turns out there's a table that always has data in it, so I've set my measure to check for data in that one before calculating and it seems to have done the job. It still seems like counter-intuitive behavior, though - if I've created a relationship to join two tables together, I shouldn't be able to display "incorrect" combinations of values without being intentional about it.